# How to wait in Android without locking the UI thread?

Tags: java, android, networking, wait, google-nearby

I have an app which uses nearby connections API. I connect x number of devices with a star strategy, then from a database I query a question on the "server" device, then send it forward to all other devices, but I have to wait till everyone answers the question (when someone answers, they send the answer to the "server" device, and it stores the answer in a list), so i need to wait on every devices till this list contains everyone's answer, then query an other question and so on. How can I achieve the waiting without freezing the UI? (And probably display some message till waiting, for example 3/5 players answered?)

Comment: Is there a reason you shouldnt use a different thread?

Comment: you should not use main thread for long operation take a look at AysncTask

Comment: Yes, I could use async task, but as far as I know, while the asynctask runs, the UI thread also runs, so at this point it would fetch the next question without waiting, while the async task in the background runs. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Ofcourse the UI thread also runs. But isnt that you want too? If the UI thread didnt run then your UI freezes which you dont want. Btw for displaying messages to the UI from other threads check out runOnUiThread()

Comment: So I need to call the next question's fetching from the asynctask's postExecute method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Threads to avoid UI freezing.

Here you have some examples and explanations from the official Android guide: [Threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Yes, I could use asynctask, but I call the next questions fetching from the UI thread, and if I use asynctask then the UI thread continues and fetches the next question without waiting for everyone's input. Or should I call the fetching from the posExecute method of the asynctask?

Comment: Using some kind of counter you can wait untill everyone has answered before pushing next question. (By some kind of counter I mean it may even be a simple integer, depending on the complexity of your needs). You just need to call the server every X seconds so it returns the answers list, then check if its equal to the players number. Otherwise, wait again X seconds and try once more.

Comment: I'm using a list where i store all answers in a given round, and when the list's size equals the player's number then we can proceed. But how to wait till this condition becomes true? Should I use a while loop and update the list from an asnyc task?

Comment: All that work should be in an async task,something like this:

`while (true){
//Check server data
if(serverData.count < playersCount) Thread.sleep(X Time) 
else break;
}`

In that code you can update UI as well, telling players how many players have answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making continuous request to the server, it would be better that the server informs you about changes in the data.

For instance, you can achieve this using Push Notifications, integrating FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) on your Android app.

This way you can execute code only when needed.